# Mac proxifier to use with Transmission?

Tags: macos, vpn, proxy, tor, transmission

I am attempting to route just my Transmission traffic through a proxy instead of all of my traffic through a VPN. My attempts at getting this to work:

1. Attempting to just route Transmission traffic through the VPN. I could not figure a suitable way to do this...
2. Attempting to use [OS X Server's Application Layer VPN](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1679968). Seems like nobody knows how to set this up (myself included)
3. Switching to uTorrent... and subsequently switching back to Transmission.
4. Setting a local port that connects to the proxy, then telling transmission to use that port. I couldn't get this working because I couldn't figure out how to [route all transmission traffic through a single port](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/776).
5. Using [proximac](https://github.com/csujedihy/proximac), but it does not support an authenticated proxy server.

After realizing that none of these solutions worked well, I then found [this recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54557/is-it-possible-to-have-per-app-network-vpn-proxy-settings), suggesting to either use a paid solution or torsocks. Since I'd rather not shell out $30, I figured I would give torsocks a shot. I managed to install it with brew, then modify the following variables in torsocks.conf:

```
TorAddress
TorPort
SOCKS5Username
SOCKS5Password
```

Doing something simple, like attempting to open up Firefox (`torsocks open -a Firefox`), results in the following output:

> [syscall] Unsupported syscall number 427. Denying the call (in tsocks_syscall() at syscall.c:165)
>   ...

And then Firefox crashes after opening. Trying the same with Transmission has similar results, and returns my IP address instead of the proxy server's after looking at ipleak. I think this might not be working because I used the SOCKS5 proxy's IP/port for `TorAddress` and `TorPort` and the proxy itself isn't a Tor proxy (I might be incredibly wrong about that).

Regardless, I am unsure about how to effectively use torsocks with Transmission. If there is a more suitable solution that will allow me to either use a proxy with Transmission or just route Transmission traffic through a VPN, I would love hearing it (and would love saving $30 in the process).

Comment: It looks like the internal library substitution alchemy is broken. Did you build tsocks from source or just installed the binaries? In the latter case, are you sure you took the ones for your OS?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm not entirely sure, but I used `brew install torsocks` to install it, if that helps